# How to create a Pgbadger report using postgres logs file?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I want to run pgbadger for postgresql logs in GCP cloudsql. I am unabel to run pgbadger report for all the logs, i can do it for single line command though.

If anyone has run pgbadger for GCP postgreSQL.

Comment: i also got issues in generating pgbadger reports but not able to. looks like some unsupported format of logs. plz let me know if you the the solution.